# Extract a GUID from XML in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a string

```
<?define customGUID=             "DA7C36F0-A749-4CC5-9575-398C06039325"?>
```

I am trying to trim out `DA7C36F0-A749-4CC5-9575-398C06039325` from this line.

To begin with I tried to set this string in a variable but I am not able to do that may be because of `<` and `?` in string, I tried:

```
set "var=<?define customGUID=            "DA7C36F0-A749-4CC5-9575-398C06039325"?>"
```

But later I was able to fetch the string somehow at runtime and now I have the variable

```
line=<?define customGUID=            "DA7C36F0-A749-4CC5-9575-398C06039325"?>
```

I am not able to figure out how can I trim only value i.e DA7C36F0-A749-4CC5-9575-398C06039325 out of this variable using batch script.

I gave it a try to trim suffix at least with:

```
set "line=%line:"?>%"
```

But getting error, can anyone help with better approach?
Note: the spaces are included in string

Comment: To grab your GUID directly from the file `myFile.xml`, and save it as the string value of a variable named `strGUID`, you could do it like this: `@For /F Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I " customGUID=" 0^<"myFile.xml" 2^>NUL') Do @Set "strGUID=%%G"`. It would be better if you werre to precede that line with `@Set "strGUID="` to make sure that no existing variable with that name exists, then you can add a third line using `If`  and `Defined strGUID` to determine whether the line was found in the named file, before you proceed with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can split the string using `"` as a delimiter, but since quotes are used to specify `for` loop options, the syntax looks a little different than usual:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "line=<?define customGUID=            "DA7C36F0-A749-4CC5-9575-398C06039325"?>"
echo !line!

for /f tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%A in ("!line!") do set "line=%%A"
echo !line!
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use this very simple trick:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "var=<?define customGUID=            "DA7C36F0-A749-4CC5-9575-398C06039325"?>"

set "i=0" & set "v0=%var:"=" & set /A i+=1 & set "v!i!=%"

echo Desired string: [%v1%]
```

If you want to know how this works, remove the `@echo off` line and carefully review what appears in the screen...

Answer (score 2):

Your command line:

```cmd
set "line=%line:"?>%"
```

does not make sense, because there is an `=`-sign missing (refer to [sub-string substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)):

```cmd
set "line=%line:"?>=%"
```

To trim away the unwanted prefix you could remove everything up to the first quotation mark:

```cmd
set "line=%line:*"=%"
```

However, this only works when you do that after having removed the suffix, because you are dealing with unbalanced quotation marks, which are problematic together with immediate variable expansion. If you want to change the order, you have to implement [escaping](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) in order not to exhibit the [redirection operator `>`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) unquoted:

```cmd
set ^"line=%line:*"=%"
set "line=%line:"?>=%"
```

---

To avoid the need of escaping depending on the input string, use [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), like this:

```cmd
set "line=<?define customGUID=            "DA7C36F0-A749-4CC5-9575-398C06039325"?>"
set line
rem // First enable delayed expansion:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Then apply it by replacing `%` with `!`:
set "line=!line:*"=!"
set "line=!line:"?>=!"
set line
rem // This restores the previous state:
endlocal
rem // At this point changes in the variable are no longer available due to localisation:
set line
```